# How to add rules to this simple validation?? -- jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a very simple form validation, here is a sample snippet of what I have that works:

```
if($('input[name=name]').val() == ""){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('prevented')
}
```

With that one rule in the if statement it is working. What I would like to do, is add a few more rules in that if statement such as:

```
input[name=email]
input[name=company]
```

But something like this doesn't work:

```
if($('input[name=name]').val() && $('input[name=email]').val() && $('input[name=company]').val() == "")
```

Is there a way to add those three rules in there? It doesn't seem to work with just the &&?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please spell out your first two rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&&` separate expressions. In your example the three expressions are:

1. `$('input[name=name]').val()`
2. `$('input[name=email]').val()`
3. `$('input[name=company]').val() == ""`

Notice in this case that the first two are just the value. The last is using type cohersion. If your attempting to avoid type cohersion (since your asking the question in the first place this is most likely so) then you will need to offer full expressions:

1. `$('input[name=name]').val() === ''`
2. `$('input[name=email]').val() === ''`
3. `$('input[name=company]').val() === ''`

Putting these in an if statement:

```
if ($('input[name=name]').val() === '' &&
  $('input[name=email]').val() === '' &&
  $('input[name=company]').val() === '') {
  ...
}
```

Or in readability terms:

```
var isNotEmpty = function(inputName) {
  var selector = 'input[name=' + inputName + ']';
  return $(selector).val() !== '';
}

var isValid = ['name', 'email', 'company'].every(isNotEmpty);

if (!isValid) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`&&` has precedence over `==`. This means that your expression is evaluated as 3 different expressions that all need to be satisfied. These are:
`$('input[name=name]').val()`, `$('input[name=email]').val()` and `$('input[name=company]').val() == ""`.

Likely what you want is for all 3 values to be equal to `""` in which case you need to do something like:

```
if($('input[name=name]').val()    == "" &&
   $('input[name=email]').val()   == "" &&
   $('input[name=company]').val() == "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare each value alone, and than combine the results via `&&`

```
if($('input[name=name]').val() == "" &&
   $('input[name=email]').val() == "" &&
   $('input[name=company]').val() == "")
```

To be honest on lazy days I wish the other way would work as well. But that's not how logic works, thankfully.